# C# equivalence of python maketrans and translate

Tags: c#, python

Where could I find code of a C# equivalence of Python maketrans and translate?
Thanks!

Comment: @paparipote: Any comment on the solutions we've provided you?

Comment: @paparipote: Hmmmm. StackOverflow had not recorded any response from you when I commented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should take you most of the way there:

```
public class MakeTrans
{
    private readonly Dictionary<char, char> d;
    public MakeTrans(string intab, string outab)
    {
        d = Enumerable.Range(0, intab.Length).ToDictionary(i => intab[i], i => outab[i]);
        //d = new Dictionary<char, char>();
        //for (int i = 0; i < intab.Length; i++)
        //    d[intab[i]] = outab[i];
    }
    public string Translate(string src)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(src.Length);
        foreach (char src_c in src)
            sb.Append(d.ContainsKey(src_c) ? d[src_c] : src_c);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

You're responsible for making sure that intab and outtab are the same length. You can add functionality for dropping letters, etc.

The dictionary construction is done in a cool LINQ-y way. It's a bit non-obvious, so the commented out code is provided and does the same thing.

Here's how it looks in python ([example lifted from here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_maketrans.htm)):

```
>>> from string import maketrans   # Required to call maketrans function.
>>>
>>> intab = "aeiou"
>>> outtab = "12345"
>>> trantab = maketrans(intab, outtab)
>>>
>>> str = "this is string example....wow!!!";
>>> print str.translate(trantab);
th3s 3s str3ng 2x1mpl2....w4w!!!
```

Here is C# test code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MakeTrans.MakeTrans mt = new MakeTrans.MakeTrans("aeiou", "12345");
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", mt.Translate("this is string example....wow!!!"));
    }
```

And here is the output:

```
th3s 3s str3ng 2x1mpl2....w4w!!!
```